# Could not find viewpager2-1.0.0.aar (androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

My Android project used to be built without any problems. And I did not change the code. But now I have this error. I updated Android Studio to version 202.7188722 and created a new project without any activity, but I got this error again:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find viewpager2-1.0.0.aar (androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0).
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/viewpager2/viewpager2/1.0.0/viewpager2- 
1.0.0.aar

Possible solution:
- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**Note:** I tested the internet connection and HTTP proxy and it had no problem.

These are my new project gradle files:

> project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> app:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hyapp.tebgeram"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

> gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Tue Mar 16 22:03:28 IRST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Comment: Have you already tried adding it "alone" as `implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried and got the same error again.

Comment: Did you check if the link https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/viewpager2/viewpager2/1.0.0/viewpager2-1.0.0.aar works in your machine?

Comment: This is the viewpager2-1.0.0.aar download link. I downloaded it and added it to the project manually, but I got this error again.

Comment: In my case by mistake I searched androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0 (not 1.1.0-beta01).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. in my case it was from the proxy and connection problems. make sure that your proxy is working fine.